# For what we use time(NULL) in C to generate =random values

Tags: c, time, random

For what we use time(NULL) in C to generate random values? What is the meaning of `time(NULL)` in this code?

```
 int i, zarodek;
    zarodek= time(NULL);
    srand(zarodek);
    int r = rand() % 49 + 1;
    printf("%d",r);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is getting the system time (in seconds).  You may optionally supply a pointer to a `time_t` value that will receive the time, but since the value is returned from the [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) function anyway, you may pass `NULL` instead (and the function will not attempt to assign to the null pointer).

The purpose of using `time` is to seed the random number generator (passing it to `srand`).  It's common to use the time, because it's generally different every time your program is run.

Note, you should only seed once (not every time you call `rand`).

Comment: _"It is getting the system time (in seconds)"_ Not necessarily in seconds (I know they are seconds on almost all implementations).

Answer (score 3):

That is seeding the random number generator with the current time.  If you don't do this, then each time you run your program, you will get the same sequence of random numbers.

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

You can either let the current time be returned by [time](http://www.cplusplus.com/time) or pass a pointer to the target struct `time_t`.